# nodejs program does not terminates even after the loop ends

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodeJs, the below program does not terminates any sugestions..

```
    var net=require("net");

    for(i=0;i<=10000;i++){
    var socket = new net.Socket();
    socket.connect(i, "localhost", function() {
    console.log(i+" Port is open");
    socket.destroy();

    });
    socket.on("error", function() {
    console.log(i+" Port is closed: ");
    socket.destroy();
    });
    }
```

Comment: how much time did you wait for?

Answer (score 0):

Socket might connected with some port.

you might not be able to see in lots of console.log so please comment that line

just comment this line :

```
  console.log(i+" Port is closed: ");
```

So you can see

console.log(i+" Port is open");

Comment: the issue is program does not terminate.. Node.js process keeps running

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to connect to localhost with a port number passed using the parameter "i" from the for loop. So, in localhost one of the port or many ports within < 10000 is open and socket is "still" trying to connect. Hence the node.js app is still running and never terminates.